# Jenkins: using parameters in command used by ssh

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to build a generic job that connects to a server and executes command.

I use the "Execute shell script on remote using ssh" job. The commands are taken from a "Text Parameter"

If i don't use the parameter but write the commands in the "Command" field, they are executed. However, when i use the parameter, ${SOME_COMMANDS}, the commands are not executed.

Should there be a way to use the text parameter in the command field?

Comment: Does it log what was attempted in the Console Output for the job?

Comment: Nope - this is the log:  : not found
[SSH] exit-status: 0
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use a parameter directly in the command field, but you could get around it by calling a shell script with a fixed name in the command field and then having the script dereference the SOME_COMMANDS variable.